# Sql Update NULL value using WHEN and WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot update the NULL rows using WHEN and WHERE. what is wrong with my query?

```
UPDATE `product` SET `city` = CASE `city`   
WHEN NULL THEN 'Gangnam' 
WHEN 'Seouls' THEN 'Seoul'
END  
WHERE city IN (NULL, 'Seoul')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `IS NULL` when comparing to `NULL`

```
UPDATE `product` 
SET `city` = 
     CASE    
          WHEN `city` IS NULL THEN 'Gangnam' 
          WHEN `city` = 'Seouls' THEN 'Seoul'
     END  
WHERE city is NULL OR city = 'Seoul'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE `product` SET `city` =  
CASE 
    WHEN `city` IS  NULL THEN 'Gangnam' 
    WHEN `city` = 'Seouls' THEN 'Seoul'
END 
WHERE city IS NULL OR city = 'Seouls'
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df293c/1)

Answer (score 0):

In sql, a comparaison with NULL is always false, so you must sue the special operator IS NULL

An alternative is to split your query in two :

UPDATE `product` SET `city` = 'Gangnam' WHERE `city` IS NULL

UPDATE `product` SET `city` = 'Seouls' WHERE `city`= 'Seoul'